# Prevent lose of form token after jquery calls post to gather some data about user client

Tags: php, jquery, html, post, token

This is very simplified example of what I am working with. Every time user visits page, the jQuery scripts calls post callback to gather some data. While doing this, I am changing the content of webToken...

My question is how to keep the token even after the post-back? I know this could be caused by rendering the entire page again. But I have tried eliminating of rendering the form completely and I still couldn't resolve this problem.

I would like to know what other issues I might come across here.

I hope this snippet will explain my problem a little bit better.

```
<head>
    <script>
        $().ready(function() {
            var file = location.pathname.substring(1, location.pathname.length);

            var data = 
            {
                platform:navigator.platform
            };

            $.post(file,
            {
                javascript: data
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

        // doing things with $_POST['javascript']...

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
            if($_POST['webToken'] != $_SESSION['webToken']) {
                echo "The token did not match!";
            }
            else {
                // do something
            }
        }
        else {
            $token = md5(uniqid());
            $_SESSION['webToken'] = $token;
            echo '<form method="post" action="SELF!!!">
            <input type="text" name="title" value="' . $title . '">
            <input type="hidden" name="webToken" value="' . $token . '">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"></form>';
        }
    ?>
</body>
```

Comment: few things i had to change in the code... i ask you to refresh page to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your `$webToken` generated only once.

- Is there any other place where you generate it?
- Is your `session` already started (either auto or manually started) ?

Also, in your post (ajax) call, you can :

- Regenerate a new token
- Return it in your call response
- Set it on call complete with jQuery

like

```
$('input[name=webToken]').val(yourNewToken);
```

Comment: I take your for the consideration.. The design is so complicated as a whole I can't pinpoint the problem myself. Thanks.